# remove empty tags on top and bottom of html string using php querypath

Tags: php, html-parsing, querypath

I'm working with php Querypath and I'm trying remove from html string all empty tag present on top and bottom of html. For example:

```
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>I want remove empty div tag on top and bottom</div>
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>other content</div>
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
```

with php querypath I would want change into:

```
      <div>I want remove empty div tag on top and bottom</div>
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>other content</div>
```

How can I do?

Comment: So you want to keep one `&nbsp;` in the middle. Then you have try using PHP DOM, http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 0):

Use replace string to replace the div with empty space.

```
str_replace(find,replace,from);
```

So, you can use the `<div>&nbsp;</div>` in find and replace it with `""` from your code.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying this but with str_replace also replace <div>&nbsp;</div> that are in middle of content that I want preserve it. I want only replace those that are on top and bottom not in middle. Have you an idea?

Comment: So, you want to replace only the `<div> </div>` part but, not what is in the middle like `&nbsp;` is that right?

Comment: Not exactly. I want delete entire tag <div>&nbsp;</div> but only those are present on top and bottom of html. if you see example above 5 "<div>&nbsp;</div>" are present in html string. I want remove first,second "<div>&nbsp;</div>" then fourth and fifth. It must remain third because it is located between "<div>I want remove empty div tag on top and bottom</div>" and "<div>other content</div>"

Comment: @Eritrea read one more time whole question... he wants to delete whole empty div parts... but not between filled divs